# How do I email to two addresses on an individual without Civi creating a new record for the second email address?

Tags: contacts, email, primary

I've read everything I can. I know you can bulk mail to non-primary email addresses. I know I can split contacts up into "Ann" and "Bob" rather than "Ann and Bob", but unfortunately it is far better for the organisation I'm working for to have "Ann and Bob" for accounting, reporting, and contacting purposes.

Is there any possibility or setting or plugin I've overlooked for being able to send single emails to both Ann and Bob's email addresses? It seems the lack of ability for multiple primary emails is a massive oversight.

I'm aware this is a core issue, but surely something has been done!

Comment: Can you explain further why you would want to have 2 people on one contact record? Because especially when you want to contact them separately I see no clear reason why you would not want to have 2 contacts.

Comment: Massive oversight? How many times have you found this raised by others?

Comment: How are you intending handling 'greetings' and 'tokens'? Are you sending an email to 'Dear Ann and Bob' twice? It may be that if you explain what the 'accounting, reporting and contacting' benefits of having Ann and Bob as a single entity, you may get some useful advice about how to address this issue.

Comment: We have sponsored students, including half sponsorships. "Ann and Bob" half-sponsor Carol. If "Ann" and "Bob" have separate accounts, only one can half-sponsor Carol, otherwise it will show that Carol has two half-sponsors, and therefore cannot be half-sponsored by someone else. Other reports are also affected. Then, if only "Ann" sponsors Carol, any email to Ann will say "your student Carol", and any email to Bob "your student {token}".

Answer (score 3):

The answer is -not- going to be multiple primary addresses as that is a contradictio in terminis.

Go household all the way: the household then half sponsors the student; a household has one primary address and can be addressed as "Dear Smith Family, thank you for sponsoring Carol."

Answer (score 2):

When you have a "primary" email address, that means the single main address. So it would be really odd to have more than one primary email address.

Comment: Agree - that would be really odd!